# Using the bootstrap order class on ONLY ONE child to manipulate the order

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I was playing around with flexbox and bootstrap, I was hoping the use the order class and some js to make some sort of "pin post to top" system but i ran into a problem.

**Problem:** Apparently the order class only properly works if all childs have an order class.

**Working:**

```
<h3>Each DIVS has order class</h3>
<div class="d-flex bg-light border mb-4">
<div class="p-5 bg-info rounded m-3 text-center font-weight-bold h1 order-2">1</div>
<div class="p-5 bg-info rounded m-3 text-center font-weight-bold h1 order-3">2</div>
<div class="p-5 bg-info rounded m-3 text-center font-weight-bold h1 order-1">3</div>
</div>
```

**Not working:**

```
<h3>Only one DIV has order class</h3>
<div class="d-flex bg-light border mb-4">
<div class="p-5 bg-danger rounded m-3 text-center font-weight-bold h1">1</div>
<div class="p-5 bg-danger rounded m-3 text-center font-weight-bold h1">2</div>
<div class="p-5 bg-danger rounded m-3 text-center font-weight-bold h1 order-1">3</div>
</div>
```

**Quesiton:** Is there any way to make the order class work if only one child as the order class? Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has a [**helper class**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes) for that: `order-first`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex bg-light border mb-4">
  <div class="p-5 bg-danger rounded m-3 text-center font-weight-bold h1">1</div>
  <div class="p-5 bg-danger rounded m-3 text-center font-weight-bold h1">2</div>
  <div class="p-5 bg-danger rounded m-3 text-center font-weight-bold h1 order-first">3</div>
</div>
```